# Optimal set of charecters to disallow/allow that prevent SQL injection perfectly?

Tags: sql, sql-injection

I know that sql injection must rely on certain set of special characters used in SQL. So here's the question:

What would be the minimal set of characters to disallow, or as large as possible, a wet to allow, that would prevent SQL injection perfectly?

I understand This is not the best nor the easiest approach to prevent SQL injection, but i just wonder questions like "can you do it even without xxx".

Answering a comment:

Just for the purpose of curiosity, some languages other than English can indeed be written normally without some special characters. for example：

Chinese:“”‘’，。！？：；——

Japanese:””’’、。！？：；ーー

English:""'',.!?：;--

Comment: No. That isn't the way to solve this problem. You need to escape your input, and you *need* to do it using the tools provided by your database system such as parameterized queries. You have no hope of writing such a function correctly yourself.

Comment: Just use parameters and pre-compiled queries.  Tried and true methods that work.

Comment: use Prepared statement instead.

Comment: It depends how draconian you want to be.  If you only allow alphanumerics plus blank, dot and comma, you're likely to be pretty safe, but that is a very restrictive set of inputs.  The O'Reilly's will hate you.  So will that Newton-Raphson's.  If you want to know why, we need to know which DBMS, because the edge cases that cause trouble are different in different DBMS.  Backslash, double quote, hash, back quote: in the right DBMS in the right context, they could cause trouble.  But blacklists and whitelists of characters are the wrong way to proceed.  Use prepared statements and placeholders.

Comment: Thats a start. You also need to exclude `/*` and `*/`. It's really not enough though. There's really no excuse for appending inline form parameters into a SQL string and submitting it. You just don't do it like that anymore.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm not very confident on the "tried" word that you are using, actually. As someone have said, testing can only prove the existence of error, not the absence of it.

Comment: @Zuoanqh . . . You should learn how databases work and what prepared/pre-compiled statements really are.  SQL injection is a problem arising from the string manipulation of queries, not of database engines running compiled queries.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ahh misunderstanding. I was saying if you say something like "they are mathematically proven to be working perfectly", it would be a better answer/comment, comparing to "tried".

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look up some examples of the kinds of ways a SQL injection attack can be leveraged against a web application with weak security architecture.  As far as the "WHY" you'll need to analyze the kinds of site user hacks that can get through what's supposed to be a locked down (but public facing) system.

I turned up this reference for further analysis:

[image: Potential SQL Injection Attacks]

You can see more at the source of this injection:
http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html

> I know that sql injection must rely on certain set of special characters used in SQL. So here's the question:

There isn't any one character that is absolutely banned, nor are there others that are trusted 100% safe.

**EDIT:** Response to a revised OP...

*A brief history of a type of SQL Injection vulnerability:*  Without developing data access APIs for your database inputs, the most common approach is "dynamically" constructing SQL statements, then executing the raw SQL (a dangerous mix of developer prepared code and outside user input).

Consider in pseudocode:

```
    @SQL_QUERY = "SELECT NAME, SOCIAL_SECURITY_NUMBER, PASSWD, BANK_ACCOUNT_NUMBER" +
        "FROM SECURE_TABLE " + "WHERE NAME = " + @USER_INPUT_NAME;

    $CONNECT_TO SQL_DB;
    EXECUTE @SQL_QUERY;
    ...
```

The expected input when obeyed is a lookup of specific user information based on a single name value input from some user form.

While it isn't my point to accidentally teach a how-to for a new generation of would-be SQL Injection hackers, you can guess that a long concatenated string of code isn't really secure if user input on a web form can also tag on anything they like to the code; including more code of their own.

The utility or danger with using dynamic sql coding is a discussion by itself. You can put a few barriers in front of a dynamic query such as this:

1. An "input handler" procedure that all inputs from app forms go through before the query code module is executed:

   ```
   run_query( parse_and_clean( @input_value ) )
   ```

This is where you look for things like string inputs too long for expected sizes (a 500 character name???? non-alpha numerical name values?)

2. Web forms can also have their own scripted input handlers.  Usually intended for validating for specific inputs (not empty, longer than three characters, no punctuation, format masks like "1-XXX-XXX-XXXX", etc.) They can also scrub for input hacks such as html coding tags, javascript, urls with remote calls, etc. Sometimes this need is best served here because the offending input is caught before it gets anywhere near the database.
3. False positives:  more often it really is just user error sending malformatted input.

These examples date to the really early days of the Internet.  There are lots of source code modules/libraries, add-ons, open-source and paid variants of attempts to make SQL injection much harder to break through into your host systems.  Dig around; there is even a huge thread on Stack Overflow that discusses this exact topic.

For the time I have been stumbling around and developing for the Internet, I share a common observation:  "perfectly" is a description of a system that has already been hacked.  You won't get there, and that isn't the point.  You should look towards being the "easy, quick target" (i.e., the Benz in the gas station with windows down, keys in ignition and owner in the restroom)

When you say  "can you do it even without...?" The answer is "sure" if it's a "Hello World" type project for some classroom assignment... hosted on your local machine... behind your router/firewall.  After all, you gotta learn somewhere.  Just be smart where you deploy stuff that isn't so secured.

It's just when you put things out open to the "world" on the Internet, you should always be thinking how the "same task" has to be done differently with a security mindset.  Same outputs as your test/dev workspace but with more precautions such as locking down obvious and commonly exploited weaknesses.

Enjoy your additional research, and hopefully this post (devoid of code examples) can encourage your mindset in helpful directions.

Onward.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I realized my question is a bit questionable, so I edited it and cleared up things to better explain what I was wondering about. Have a look if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that sql injection must rely on certain set of special characters used in SQL. So here's the question:
>
> What would be the minimal set of characters to disallow, or as large as possible, a wet to allow, that would prevent SQL injection perfectly?

This is the wrong approach to this topic. Instead you need to understand why and how SQL injections happen. Then you can work out measures which prevent them.

Because the cause of SQL injections is the incorporation of user supplied data into SQL command. [If the user supplied fragments are not processed properly, they could modify the intention of the SQL command.](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/89.html)

Here the aspect of *proper processing* is crucial, which again depends on the developer’s intention  of how the user provided data is supposed to be interpreted. In most cases it’s a literal value (e. g., string, number, date, etc.) and sometimes a SQL keyword (e. g., sort order `ASC` or `DESC`, operators, etc.) or even an identifier (e. g., column name, etc.).

These all follow certain syntax rules which can the user provided data can either be validated against and/or enforced:

- **Prepared statements** are the first choice for literal values. They separate the SQL statement and parameter values so that latter can’t be mistakenly interpreted as something other than literal values.
- **White listing** can always be used when the set of valid values it limited, which is the case for SQL keywords and identifiers.

So looking at the use cases for user provided data and the corresponding options that prevent SQL injections, there is no need to restrict the set of allowed characters globally. Better stick to the methods which are best practice and have proved effective.

And if you happen to have a use case that doesn’t fit the mentioned, e. g., allowing users to provide something more complex than an atomic language elements like an arbitrary filter expression, you should break them down into their atoms to be able to ensure their integrity.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning types of error that involves sql keyword and on. I was really worrying about user-supplied code fragments only, but nonetheless learned something from your answer.